# Semantic confusion over the meaning of "order matters/is important"

Tags: probability, permutations, combinations

Doubts have been expressed as to what exactly "order matters/is important" means in relation to the following question on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080203/40-cards-4-are-aces-probability-of-1-ace-when-drawing-2-cards-at-ramdo/2080213#2080213)

"In a deck of 40 cards there are 4 aces. What is the probability that when drawing two cards only one ace is drawn."

There can be two cases: first card is the ace, or second card is the ace.

One view expressed is that since both cases refer to one **event**, order is not important.

The other view is that since we are considering two possible **permutations**, order **is** important.

**Or put differently, is "order important/matters" if**

**(a)** the order is **specified**, e.g. first card is an ace, or

**(b)** the order is **unspecified**, i.e. all possible orders are to be considered

I have the feeling that both the interpretations are being used on this site by different people.

It would be good if some one could give a definitive opinion on this matter.

Comment: @turkeyhundt: The question isn't w.r.t the particular problem. I have edited the question to make the dichotomy clearer: **specified order** = ?, **unspecified order** = ?

Comment: @turkeyhundt As you say, order is important(/specified) *in each case*, but as either case is part of the event, then order is not-important(/unspecified) *in the event*.

Comment: @Graham Kemp: The precise question I am asking (forget about the particular problem, and the ways available to solve such problems is) : **is order important because it has been specified, therefore must be important; or is order important when left unspecified, because then all possible orders  must be considered.**

Comment: *All possible* orders must be considered when the order is *unspecified* because the order is *not important* and it *does not matter* which of the possible orders occurs for the event to happen.  However, if the order *were important* then only the *specified* order would need be considered because that is the *order that matters*.  (See the posted answer for further clarification.)

Comment: @Graham Kemp: It seems that you have taken the opposite view of the meaning of "order matters" at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489934/weird-probability-question-grapes-olives/1489961#1489961

Answer (score 2):

For the experiment of drawing two cards from the specified deck, define the random variable, $A$ as the count of aces drawn, and the event $A_1, A_2$ as "an ace is drawn first" and "... second" respectively.

---

In the event of $A=1$, the order is *not important*.   It *does not matter* whether the single ace is the first or second card drawn.   The order is *not specified* by the event of "exactly one ace is drawn".

One solution is that $\mathsf P(A=1)={\tbinom 41\tbinom {36}1}\bigm/{\tbinom {40}2}$, which is the probability for selecting 1 from 4 aces and 1 from 36 non-aces given that 2 from 40 cards are selected.   This solution does not concern itself with the order the cards are selected –in either numerator nor denominator–.

---

Another solution is that $\mathsf P(A=1)= \mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2^\complement)+\mathsf P(A_1^\complement\cap A_2) = (\dfrac 4{40}\cdot\dfrac{36}{39})+(\dfrac {36}{40}\cdot\dfrac 4{39})$

This solution partitions the event into two subsets, each an event in which the order the cards are drawn *is* important.   For *each* part, *it matters* that the ace is drawn first or second.   $A_1\cap A_2^\complement$ *specifies* the order of the cards, as does the other part, $A_1^\complement\cap A_2$.

The solution to each part clearly concerns itself with the order of the draw.   The relevant terms are obtained by evaluating, $\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2^\complement)=\mathsf P(A_1)\mathsf P(A_2^\complement\mid A_1)$ and $\mathsf P(A_1^\complement\cap A_2)=\mathsf P(A_1^\complement)\mathsf P(A_2\mid A_1^\complement)$

However, as the event is the union of the parts — either part satisfies the event — then, as a whole, the order is *not important*.   That is, because the order is not important, we may measure the probability for each ordering, then add these results to obtain the measure for the event.

Comment: Awaiting your comments on  a diametrically opposite view taken by you for a similar question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489934/weird-probability-question-grapes-olives/1489961#1489961