# In how many ways can 6 people buy three flavour ice cream bowls?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I'm really weak when it comes to discrete math and combinatorics, so I wanna make sure whether I'm thinking corectly.

> An ice cream store sells 5 different flavours of ice cream. For a bowl, one chooses at random three kinds (not necessarily different); the order does not matter. In how many ways can 6 people buy such bowls so that that each flavour is taken at least once.

I recognize this as inclusion-exclusion principle. Let's assume we have $n$ different, numbered flavours. Using "stars and bars" we find

$${3+n-1\choose n-1}$$ ways of making arbitrary bowls from $n$ flavours.

Now lets setup the inclusion-exclusion principle:

- $X$ - 6 people buy arbitrary bowls: $${3+5-1\choose 5-1}^6$$
- $A_i$ - nobody bought $i$th flavour, 4 left: $${3+4-1\choose 4-1}^6$$
- $A_i\cap A_j$ - nobody bought $i$th nor $j$th flavour, 3 left: $${3+3-1\choose 3-1}^6$$
  and so on.
  So the answer, according to this logic, should be $$\sum_{i=0}^4(-1)^i{5\choose i}{3+(5-i)-1\choose (5-i)-1}^6=\sum_{i=0}^4(-1)^i{5\choose i}{7-i\choose 4-i}^6$$
  Is that correct? Thanks.

Comment: the upper bound of sigma notation must go up to $5$ instead of $4$ ... except for that , your answer is correct

Comment: Well, I thought since i=5 introduces (2 choose -1), which is 0, I will just skip it.

Comment: your answer gives correct value, because for $5$ , it is zero. However , if you want to write correct formula , then you must use $5$ in your sigma notation

Comment: Oh okay, thank you very much!

Comment: Combos using stars and bars aren't equiprobable.

Comment: (Acceptable ways) = (Total ways)/P(all 5 flavors chosen), so probability comes in willy-nilly. Btw, the phrase "order does not matter" is susceptible to various interpretations, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080620/semantic-confusion-over-the-meaning-of-order-matters-is-important

Answer (score 1):

If each person is choosing uniformly and at random, (remember, a person is allowed to choose all $3$ of the same flavor), we want yo count putting $18$ distinct balls being put in $5$ distinct boxes with no box empty.

So either we count it as $\Large5!{18\brace k}$, using Stirling numbers of the second kind, or

use inclusion-exclusion, $\Large 5^{18} - \binom51 4^{18}+\binom52 3^{18}-\binom53 2^{18} +\binom541^{18}$

Comment: Okay, so we have $6$ people; $A, B, C, D, E, F$ and every person can select 3 (not necessarily different) flavours. So we create surjections such that $f(person, i) = flavor$ for $i=1,2,3$. Doesn't that imply that we care about order of the flavours? Because we can create two distinct functions:

$f(A, 1) = banana$, $f(A,2) = strawberry$, $f(A,3) = lemon$ and
$g(A, 1) = banana$, $g(A,2) = lemon$, $g(A,3) = strawberry$

when it's stated that the order does not matter. Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: Whereas I think my solution treats such cases as $f(A)=\{banana,strawbery,lemon\}$ where the right hand side is a multiset.

Comment: In that case, one point is that the persons don't matter, so you might just as well count putting $18$ balls in $5$ bins with at least one in each, so $\Large\binom{18-1}{5-1} = 2380$

Comment: Re it is stated that "order does not matter" pl see my comments against your post.