# In how many ways can three 3-sided dice be rolled if order doesn’t matter?

Tags: combinatorics

I found out that there is a total of 10 using tree diagrams and then removing the duplicates as order doesn’t matter. However, I want to know how to do this with a formula.

Comment: [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) might help. Note that you must find the number of tuples $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb N^3$ with $a+b+c=3$. Here $a$ stands for the number of dice that show face $1$, et cetera. The $3$ on RHS corresponds with the fact that you use $3$ dice in total. Note that $\binom{3+2}2=10$.

Comment: @drhab Some (not all) of $\{a,b,c\}$ can be zero.

Comment: @stoic-santiago Yes, and $0\in\mathbb N$ in my perception.

Comment: It is better to use the word "unordered" rather than "order doesn't matter" as the latter usage is susceptible to semantic confusion. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2080620/semantic-confusion-over-the-meaning-of-order-matters-is-important

Answer (score 2):

Since the order doesn't matter, an outcome is determined completely by how many times a certain side of the die shows up when three dice are rolled. In other words, the number of ways you can roll three identical (i.e., the order doesn't matter) three-sided dice is the same as the number of tuples $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ with $0 \le x_i \le 3$, $x_i \in \Bbb Z$, and $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 3$. This is just $${3 + 3 - 1 \choose 3} = {5\choose 3} = 10$$
by [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)), for instance.